# crystal report not working in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, crystal-reports, sharepoint-2007

When i try to deploy crystal report application on sharepoint server i get the following error
The vs2008 application works fine locally.But when it is deployed on sharepoint server it gives this type of error..Plz help

Unknown Query Engine Error Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\EmpReport {C388758D-9AE2-4E60-A4D1-E18BFB6F3703}.rpt:
Unknown Query Engine Error   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.ReplaceConnection(Object oldConnection, Object newConnection, Object parameterFields, Object crDBOptionUseDefault)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)

i really cant figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue is something to do with Code Access Security.Refer these answers [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/198de908-46ae-43b2-8993-fb8caa7b01c6) & [2](http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/22526/).